# How to use UISearchBar as input accessory view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uisearchbar

I'm trying to use a UISearchBar as an input accessory view so that it can animated present together with keyboard, my first solution is,

1. Creates a new class MySearchBar which extends UISearchBar and implements inputAccessoryView property from UIResponder.
2. In my view controller, I create a new MySearchBar instance named mySearchBar, and **set its inputAccessoryView to be itself** (this creates circular reference, but I have the code to break it).
3. Each time I want to present the search bar, I first add it to controller's view, and call its becomeFirstResponser method.
4. After the keyboard presents, calls [[mySearchBar inputAccessoryView] becomeFirstResponser].

This works very well on my iPhone 4 with iOS 4.3.  However, on iPhone 5.0 simulator the keyboard doesn't show up only after I tap on the search bar (see the image below).

[image]

Then I try my second solution,

1. Creates a new class named MyTextField which extends UITextField, in the implementation creates a UISearchBar and use it as input accessory view of MyTextField.
2. In my view controller class I add a dummy MyTextField to the view hierarchy.
3. Each time I want to present the search bar, I simply call [myTextField becomeFirstResponser].
4. After the keyboard presents, calls [[myTextField inputAccessoryView] becomeFirstResponser].

With this solution I have no problem presenting keyboard, and focusing on the input accessory view (the search bar), however, I cannot input any text when the search bar is being focused.

Anyone know what's going wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue with setting a UISearchBar as its own input accessory view. First click - bar would move, second click - keyboard shows. Dismissing the keyboard removed the bar from the screen entirely. My solution was to respond to keyboard showing and hiding notifications manually and do away with input accessory. Then I would and animate the bar accordingly. If your search bar is not at the bottom, like mine is, you will have to tailor the animation to your needs. I hope this is helpful!

In viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

The other methods:

```
- (NSTimeInterval)keyboardAnimationDurationForNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {    
    NSDictionary* info = [notification userInfo];
    NSValue* value = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
    NSTimeInterval duration = 0;
    [value getValue:&duration];

    return duration;
}

-(void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)n {

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(self.mSearchBar.frame.origin.x, self.mSearchBar.frame.origin.y - 216, self.mSearchBar.frame.size.width, self.mSearchBar.frame.size.height);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:[self keyboardAnimationDurationForNotification:n] delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews animations:^{
    self.mSearchBar.frame = frame;
    } completion:nil];
}

-(void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)n {
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(self.mSearchBar.frame.origin.x, self.mSearchBar.frame.origin.y + 216, self.mSearchBar.frame.size.width, self.mSearchBar.frame.size.height);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:[self keyboardAnimationDurationForNotification:n] delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews animations:^{
    self.mSearchBar.frame = frame;
    } completion:nil];
}
```

Removing the observer when you are done is a good idea (probably in viewDidUnload):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```